# Add timestamp to name of created VM's instance in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, yandexcloud

I deploy some VM's instances in my cloud infrastructure with bash script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
instance_name="vm"
# create instance
yc compute instance create \
  --name $instance_name \
  --hostname reddit-app \
  --memory=2 \
  ...
```

I need to add timestamp to instance's name in format `vm-DD-MM_YYYY-H-M-S`.
For debug I tried to set value `instance_name=$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S)` but got the error:

```
ERROR: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = Request validation error: Name: invalid resource name
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Presumably either underscore, hyphen or numbers are not allowed in the name. Try removing them or checking the YC docs.

Comment: @l0b0 Thanks for reply. I found that underscore may be relevant to this issue. I tried set `instance_name=$(date +%s)`. This should display only numbers without underscore, hyphen. But still looking the error.

Comment: Then I can only suggest looking at the docs. They may have any number of restrictions, like length or not including numbers.

Comment: Assuming the instance name should start with alphabet, please try: `instance_name="vm-$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S)"`.

Comment: @l0b0 The doc says:
"The name may contain lowercase Latin letters, numbers, and hyphens.
The first character must be a letter. The last character can't be a hyphen. The maximum length of the name is 63 characters". I modified my script with these recommendations and it works now.

Comment: @tshiono Thanks for reply. It's important notice. But It should not be used underscore in name of instance. Finally string is as follows: `instance_name="redditapp-$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S)"`. I'm ready to confirm your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Yandex Cloud` documentation says:
"The name may contain lowercase Latin letters, numbers, and hyphens. The first character must be a letter. The last character can't be a hyphen. The maximum length of the name is 63 characters".

I changed my script following the recommendations and it works now:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
instance_name="vm-$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S)"
# create instance
yc compute instance create \
  --name $instance_name \
  --hostname reddit-app \
  --memory=2 \
  ...
```

Comment: Nice!

In linux it is also useful to use ISO dates so that you can easily order files using their name: 20210121.